# Time shift of solution to an ODE is itself a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to show that time shifts of a solution to an ODE are solutions.

Suppose $\dot x(t)=f(x(t)).$

I know I need to show that $\dot x(t+p)=f(x(t+p))$ for some $p\in \mathbb{R}$.

I know that $$\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{d}{d(t+p)}\frac{d(t+p)}{dt}=\frac{d}{d(t+p)}$$

What do I need to do now?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be a solution of the equation

$$\dot{x}(t)=f(x(t)).$$

Let $T\in \mathbb{R}$ and define $y(t):=x(t+T)$. We have by the chain rule

$$ \dot{y}(t) = \dot{x}(t+T)\cdot \frac{d}{dt}(t+T) = \dot{x}(t+T) = f(x(t+T))= f(y(t)).$$

Hence, $y$ is again a solution of our original equation. Thus the time shift of a solution of our ODE is again a solution of our ODE. Note that it is crucial that $f$ does not depend explicitely on $t$. Such ODEs are called autonomous.